# h2o automl auc coefficient low

Tags: python, h2o

I am running H2O AutoML on data with 3000 observations (for binary classification) with 10% default. The AUC of the best model is very low (0.6 on the test data). How can I maximize it?

Comment: With 2 computers

Comment: Adding more CPUs will not improve model performance.

Comment: @Adata If you found my answer sufficient, can you please accept the answer below?

Answer (score 3):

The AutoML algorithm has tried it's best on the data you gave it, however there are few things you can try:

- You can run the AutoML process for longer than you are currently running it by increasing `max_runtime_secs`.
- It sounds like you have imbalanced data in your binary classification problem (where the minority class is 10%) so you could try setting `balance_classes` to True.
- You can do doing some manual [feature engineering](http://www.feat.engineering/) on your data to transform existing features or create additional features.
- The best solution is to collect more training data (though that may not be possible).